# If two permutation groups on the same set are isomorphic are they the same?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

For any permutation groups on a set $S$ say $G,H\subseteq \text{Sym}(S)$ is it true that $G\cong H\implies G=H$? My gut says its trivially false or trivially true i.e. this is likey a dumb question, but I'm confused.

Comment: Consider $G=\{id,(1\,2)\}$ and $H=\{id,(2\,3)\}$ in $\text{Sym}(\{1,2,3\})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In $S_6$, the group generated by the cycle $(123456)$ is cyclic of order 6, and the group generated by $(12)(345)$ is cyclic of order 6. But, they are not the same. This example shows also that they may not even be conjugate subgroups.

Comment: Or the subgroups $\langle(1\ 2),\ (3\ 4)\rangle$ and $\langle(1\ 2)(3\ 4),\ (1\ 3)(2\ 4)\rangle$ of $S_4.$

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't true. Consider $S_5$ (not minimal but easy). Then consider the groups $\langle (1\,2)\rangle$ and $\langle (3\, 4)\rangle$. Both are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but they're not equal.

Comment: Those two subgroups are really "same" — they are conjugate in $S_5$.